# jQuery fire an event and receive it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire event globally and receive it anywhere in my application. Based on the event received, I want to perform some operations.

I have a multistep form when user click the next button, I want to trigger an event

```
function multiStep(){
    $('.body').trigger('stepchanged');

}
```

Now I want to receive stepchanged in another function and perform some operations.

```
if (stepchanged){
//do something
}
```

How to receive the events?
Thanks

Comment: Just a comment to your previous question, it should be `var item = $('#steps-uid-0-p-'+ currentId + ' .finders').length;`

Answer (score 1):

You need an event handler that sets the variable.

```
`$(".body").on("stepchanged", function() { 
    stepchanged = true;
})`
```

Although there's not really any need for the event handler, unless it does other things. You can just set the global variable in `multistep()`.

Comment: How can i send numeric value a swell: 
here
 `$('.body').trigger('stepchanged', currentIndex); `

Comment: Use `function(event, currentIndex)` in the event handler.